# What kind of protections are needed to control an AC motor (230 V) using a microcontroller?

Tags: motor, solid-state-relay

I need some guidance with surge-protection of the SSR and also how to safely bring the motor to stop (since it's an RL load, the inductive current has to die out). I found a schematic online, but have some difficulties understanding it. Please help me understand the 2 points below.

[image: Relay to drive Motor]

In above figure, input ports are 2 and 3 for the SSR. Ports 6 and 8 are for output, so when SSR is on, there's a short between 6 and 8. When SSR is off, there's an open circuit between 6 and 8.

1. What I don't understand is the Zs, the surge protection circuit.
   When SSR is off, the mains, the motor and Zs are in series. Zs is an
   RC circuit in series (this I got from another site where they were talking
   of the same circuit). So basically, when SSR is off, we have RLC in
   series across mains. How does the motor switch off then? Wouldn't
   the mains keep driving the motor?
2. A motor is an RL load, so once the relay is off there will need to
   be an alternative path for the current to die out. I believe
   there should be a Resistor in parallel across the motor, for the
   inductive energy to dissipate, once the SSR is off.

Answer (score 1):

1. The snubber will be designed such that it passes minimal power at 50/60Hz, therefore the motor will not be "powered", although it may see a very small amount of passed power.
2. The motor's windings themselves will act as a shunt during shutdown - they can be viewed as purely-inductive, purely-resistive, or RL in parallel. Current will oscillate momentarily within the motor before dying to nothing (or near-nothing).